# Uso do STRING_AGG no Postgresql

Tags: string

Boa tarde amigos,

Utilizei o script abaixo:

SELECT  id_docente
, STRING_AGG(distinct no_municipio, ' / ') AS "Municipios"
FROM
public.tb_uf
INNER JOIN
public.ts_docente
ON (tb_uf.co_uf = ts_docente.co_uf) AND (tb_uf.co_municipio = ts_docente.co_municipio)
GROUP BY id_docente

Que me deu o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se existe um comando que me diga qual a dependência nos municípios, assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Explique de onde viria a "depedência".

Comment: Dependência é se pertence a Rede Estadual ou Municipal ou Federal ou Privada; e o comando está na ts_docente

Comment: Uma coluna ? Tentou conctenar a "no_municipio" ?